# Can´t cast to an actor - UE4 BP

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I´m trying to cast to an actor inside a widget button so I can toggle the visibility of a specific part of the actor itself.
The problem is that I don´t know what I have o put on the object node to make the cast work.

[image: BP inside the widget]

Comment: "Cranio" is the name of the actor

Comment: It's not possible to answer without understanding more about what you're trying to do. Where is this actor? How did you plan to get a reference to it?

Comment: I´m sorry, I´m new to UE4. I want to toggle the visibility of a specific component inside an actor. I want to do this action by clicking in a button on a widget

The actor itself will be spawned on the map by clicking a button.

Comment: I know that this can be done because I saw a video of Zak Parrish from Unreal doing something similar, but I can't find it

Comment: When you spawn the actor, keep a reference to it in a variable.

Comment: Thanks! That actually worked, but I do know there is an easy way if I find it I´ll post it here. https://imgur.com/5EqHj24

Answer (score 1):

You can do "get all actors of class" before casting, select the actor you want "Cranio" then from the array square output from "get all actors from class" drag out a "Get (copy)" and connect its output with "object" in the "cast to Cranio".

Look at the image to visualize.

[image]